# I want to insert the input data into database using webservice

Tags: php, web-services, apache-flex

I refer the below links http://www.discorganized.com/php/a-complete-nusoap-and-flex-example-part-1-the-nusoap-server/

**Code:**

```
$client = new nusoap_client("http://localhost/jenny_flowers/online-shopping/webservice/index.php?wsdl",array('trace' => 1));
$in_contact=array ('first_name'=>'sona','last_name' => 'sdsdsd','email' => 'ssdsd','phone_number' => 'sdsd');
$result = $client->call('insertContact', $in_contact);
if ($result){ echo "OK";
} else { echo "Error";
}
```

But it displays

`Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\jenny_flowers\online-shopping\webservice\lib\nusoap.php on line 7266`

What is the actual issue? help.

Comment: That library published on 2010 and seems to be open for sql injection and I doubt it will work with latest PHP.

Answer (score 1):

First have connect file

connect.php

```
<?php

$mysql_db_hostname = "localhost";

$mysql_db_user = "root";

$mysql_db_password = "";

$mysql_db_database = "your database";







$con = @mysqli_connect($mysql_db_hostname, $mysql_db_user, $mysql_db_password,

 $mysql_db_database);



if (!$con) {

 trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());

}
?>
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php
include_once('connect.php');

error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE ); 
  //$first_name= $_GET['first_name'];
  $last_name= $_GET['last_name'];
  $email= $_GET['email'];
  $phone_number= $_GET['phone_number'];
{


$insert="INSERT INTO //your_table_name(first_name,last_name,email,phone_number)values
                                                        ('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$phone_number')";

  $result = mysqli_query($con, $insert);
                if(!$result)
                {

                    print("invalid query");
                }
                else
                {


                    $output['success']=1;
                    $output['message']="Insert records successfully";
                    print(json_encode($output));

                }
            }
?>
```

Have JSON Viwer in your browser to view the json output
otherwise you can used echo in it